# OpenCL work groups, work items, local memory concepts

Tags: c, memory, opencl, gpu

I'm trying to wrap my head around this stuff. Obviously how our data is subdivided will be critical to performance utilization. Am i on the right track here? We use an image of size 1024x1024 and will do a simple arbitrary calculation as an example.

First, a GPU device has several cores, also called *compute units* (CU). Each compute unit is further subdivided into a number processing elements (PE) that do the actual work. In OpenCL we find the number of CU using CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS. But how do we find the PEs? Can't seem to find the flag in the OpenCL specification.

Global size will be 1024x1024 = 1048576 image pixes that we will perform an operation on on each pixel.

(1)Now, we subdivide the image into regions called Work Groups. Work groups execute on CUs, CORRECT? I.e. one work group maps to exactly one CU?

(2)Say that our GPU has 16 CU and we set our Work Groups to be 16. Now each work group will have 65536 work items executing?

(3)Now our image is broken into 16 parts executing concurrently all at the same time?

(4)Each group have 65536 pixels to crunch on its own CU. Since CU are composed of several PE, are those 65536 pixels further subdivided and processed concurrently? What will be better to have - lots work groups and lesser work items (single pixels) or the opposite?

(5)Local memory... local memory is said to fixed at a certain max at CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE. What if i have a __kernel const char *ker(__local uint *locMem){...} and upon initialization i set locMem to be bigger than the max? What performance repercussions will that have? Also, local memory is visible only in a single CU and is shared among all PE in that particular CU?

(6)Inside a single kernel, i.e. one PE, what boundaries i have on setting local vars? What will happen if i set too much local vars? Same question goes for CU.

Sorry for bombardment, must it's mystery and other threads discussing these issues are all in different contexts or similarly vague as the book i'm using.

Comment: For now don't focus as much on hardware; instead, follow the general guidelines - 128-256 work items per work group (threads per block) is a good starting point; spawn as many work groups as needed to cover the entire image. Then benchmark, profile and optimize your launch configuration. Processing multiple pixels in one thread is a viable optimization strategy too.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So i setup with 256 pixels instead of the 65536? This gives me 4096 groups that will execute on my 16 CUs -> 16 groups at a time? :)

Comment: You need to try things first, before asking these questions. 65536 threads per block are not even supported; your kernel launch would have failed if you specify such configuration. And don't worry about how groups are distributed across CUs; as long as you have enough groups, that will keep device saturated.